# Export pubsub data to object storage using SCIO

Tags: spotify-scio

I am trying to export Cloud Pub/Sub streams to Cloud Storage as described by this post by Spotify [Reliable export of Cloud Pub/Sub streams to Cloud Storage](https://labs.spotify.com/2017/04/26/reliable-export-of-cloud-pubsub-streams-to-cloud-storage/) or this post by Google [Simple backup and replay of streaming events using Cloud Pub/Sub, Cloud Storage, and Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/simple-backup-and-replay-streaming-of-events-using-cloud-pubsub-cloud-storage-and-cloud-dataflow)

PubSub creates oubounded `PCollection` (or `SCollection` in SCIO) but `saveastextfile` requires `BoundedCollection`.

Is there any way to overcome this ?

Answer (score 1):

The new [dynamic IO](https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/master/scio-core/src/main/scala/com/spotify/scio/io/dynamic/package.scala) module should support saving unbounded collection to files.

However note that the approach in that Spotify article doesn't use Dataflow since it has a lot of custom logic for SLA/bucketing/reliability reasons. So YMMV.